# Xpath local-name vs URL using XSLT (Xpath 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am reading the value of username and password from the XML file using the variable.

```
    <xsl:variable name="routingDoc" select="document('local:///Config/routing-config.xml')"/>
```

Below is XML file I am reading:

```
    <WSSecurity>
    <destination clientURL="/somethingURL">
        <username>James</username>
        <password>12345</password>
    </destination>
</WSSecurity>
```

when I am using below snippet of the code the Xpath doesn't work when I am using URL approach.

```
<xsl:variable name="routingDoc" select="document('local:///B2B/routing-config.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="username">
    <xsl:value-of select="$routingDoc/my:WSSecurity/my:desination/my:username"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="password">
    <xsl:value-of select="$routingDoc/my:WSSecurity/my:desination/my:password"/>
</xsl:variable>
    <!--<xsl:variable name="password" select="$WSdoc/WSSecurity/desination/password/text()"/>-->
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">   *** Username is: <xsl:value-of select="$username"/>
    </xsl:message>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">   *** Password is: <xsl:value-of select="$password"/>
    </xsl:message>
```

I get the username and password as blank.However when I am using local-name I am getting the value? Can anyone explain why? I think it's because of the namespaces I did tried this as well

```
$routingDoc/WSSecurity/desination/username
```

When I used its working fine.

```
$routingDoc/*[local-name()='WSSecurity']/*[local-name()='destination']/*[local-name()='username']
```

Please advise.

Comment: The XML file that you show us has no namespaces. Why are you using the `my:` prefix to address the nodes in this document, and what is the namespace bound to this prefix?

Comment: The XML file was created my me and it doesn't have any prefix or namespace attached to it. When I tried this also it didn't work. ($routingDoc/WSSecurity/desination/username)

Comment: desination != destination